# Determine minimum flextable row height to fit all contents when width is fixed

Tags: r, flextable

I want to split flextables that are too long into multiple flextables and insert into multiple PowerPoint slides. I need to know the minimum row height when the flextable is printed, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. If the row height is set very low, the printed flextable will have a row height that is larger than the manual height setting, but I don't know how to extract that information.

In the following example, I want to know the height of the printed row that contains the long label. The height is set to 0.25, but that is not the printed height.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)

d <- data.frame(x = "a really long label about nothing at all")

ft <- flextable(d) %>% 
  width(j = 1, width = 1) %>% 
  height_all(0.25) %>% 
  set_table_properties(layout = "fixed") %>% 
  hrule(rule = "exact") 
ft
```

```r
ft %>% dim
#> $widths
#> x 
#> 1 
#> 
#> $heights
#> [1] 0.25 0.25
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You may need function `dim_pretty()`, see https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/layout.html#pretty-dimensions

Comment: @DavidGohel But `dim_pretty()` also changes the width. I want to fix the width and then determine the height. I wonder if it's possible to add an argument to `dim_pretty()` which will allow the user to select which dimension to optimize: width, height, or both.

Comment: `dim_retty()` return minimum estimated widths and heights for each table columns and rows

Comment: @DavidGohel Yes, but sometimes I want to fix the width of the columns because I know what they should be, and I want the text to be wrapped. It seems `dim_pretty()` always wants to avoid wrapping of cell contents and thus extends the width to accommodate the row with the most number of characters (longest).

Comment: OK, sorry I misunderstood. There is no solution in flextable, but this is an interesting suggestion